# Shiny R plotly gantt chart

Tags: shiny, plotly, gantt-chart

i plotted shiny Gantt-chart as per my requirement,
we require some interactive way for Display shiny gantt chart which is linked with one table view.
also currently gantt chart seems hover when we hover begin or end if task,
we are looking for output when anywhere click on task bar.

please suggest me how can we do this.
thanks

Comment: You could use Plotlys `event_data("plotly_hover")`: https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-hover-events/ you can then ask the x and y value of the hover event and use it in a different output.

Comment: we also want critical path with gantt chart and with dependencies of other task related linked gantt chart using shiny R,
which is seems like other gantt chart as on redmine or as like asana gantt.